# Android Jetpack Paging 3: PagingSource with Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging, android-paging-library, android-paging-3

I'm using latest Jetpack libraries.
Pagination3 version: `3.0.0-alpha05`
Room Version : `2.3.0-alpha02`

My entities have Long as `PrimaryKey` and Room can generate `PagingSource` for other than `Int` type.

```
error: For now, Room only supports PagingSource with Key of type Int.
    public abstract androidx.paging.PagingSource<java.lang.Long, com.example.myEntity>` getPagingSource();
```

Therefore I tried to implement my custom `PagingSource`, like [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-paged-data#pagingsource) suggest.

The problem is **Data Refresh**, since Room's generated code handles data refresh and with my code I'm not being able to handle this scenario.

Any suggestions how to implement custom `PagingSource` for `Room` that also handles `Data Refresh`?

Answer (score -3):

Since you have 'refresh' scenario and using Room db, I am guessing you are using Paging3 with network+local db pattern(with Room db as local cache).

I had a similar situation with network + local db pattern. I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, or your situation is the same as the one I had, but I'll share what I did anyway.

What I was using:

- Paging3: 3.0.0-beta01
- Room: 2.3.0-beta02

What I did was let Room library to create PagingSource (with the key of `Int`), and let [RemoteMediator](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-overview) handle all the other cases, such as fetching the data from network when refreshing and/or appending, and inserting them into db right after fetch success.

My `dao` function for creating PagingSource from Room Library:

```kotlin
@Query("SELECT * FROM article WHERE isUnread = 1")
fun getUnreadPagingSource(): PagingSource<Int, LocalArticle>
```

In my case I defined Repository class to have `dao` class in its constructor to call the function above from repository when creating [Pager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/paging/Pager) class.

My custom RemoteMediator class looks something like this below:

- Note: In my case, there is no PREPEND case so `RemoteMediator#load` function always returns `true` when the value of the argument `loadType` is `LoadType.PREPEND`.

```kotlin
class FeedMediator(
    private val repository: FeedRepository
) : RemoteMediator<Int, LocalArticle>() {

    ... 

    override suspend fun load(
        loadType: LoadType,
        state: PagingState<Int, LocalArticle>
    ): MediatorResult = runCatching {
        when (loadType) {
            LoadType.PREPEND -> true
            LoadType.REFRESH -> {
                feedRepository.refresh()
                false
            }
            LoadType.APPEND -> {
                val continuation = feedRepository.continuation()
                if (continuation.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    true
                } else {
                    loadFeedAndCheckContinuation(continuation)
                }
            }
        }
    }.fold(
        onSuccess = { endOfPaginationReached -> MediatorResult.Success(endOfPaginationReached) },
        onFailure = {
            Timber.e(it)
            MediatorResult.Error(it)
        }
    )

    private suspend fun loadFeedAndCheckContinuation(continuation: String?): Boolean {
        val feed = feedRepository.load(continuation)
        feedRepository.insert(feed)
        return feed.continuation.isNullOrEmpty()
    }
```

Finally you can create `Pager` class.

```kotlin
fun createFeedPager(
        mediator: FeedMediator<Int, LocalArticle>,
        repository: FeedRepository
    ) = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = FETCH_FEED_COUNT,
            enablePlaceholders = false,
            prefetchDistance = PREFETCH_DISTANCE
        ),
        remoteMediator = mediator,
        pagingSourceFactory = { repository.getUnreadPagingSource() }
    )
```

I hope it helps in some way..

Other references:

- https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db
- https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/getting-on-same-page-with-paging-3.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cwqGOku2a4

---

EDIT:
After reading the doc again, I found a statement where [the doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db) clearly states:

> RemoteMediator to use for loading the data from the network into the local database.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response!

I remember that I didn't have Network requirement, but I needed to support `Long` Primary keys, which unfortunately are not supported by `Paging3` `PagingSource`.
I ended up creating extra row for `Int` and another for `Long`. So that `PagingSource` can still use `Int` key.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, as the answer doesn't mention how to implement custom PagingSource or how to handle non-Integers as PrimaryKey with paging 3 library and Room.